# When i used RelativeLayout addview in Android, the view is extrusion.How can i do it?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

When I use addView in RelativeLayout like this:

```
for (BigClicleTagInfoBean info : bean.tags) {
            BigClicleTagView tagView = null;
            boolean isLeftTag = info.isLeftDirection();
            if(isLeftTag) {
                tagView = new BigClicleTagLeftView(this.getContext(), null);
            } else {
                tagView = new BigClicleTagRightView(this.getContext(), null);
            }
            tagView.setData(info);
            tagView.setTagViewListener(this);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            int marginLeft = 0;
            int marginRight = 0;
            int marginTop = (int)(info.pos_y * pictureHeight) + 10;

            if(isLeftTag) {
                marginLeft = (int) (info.pos_x * Global.widthPixels);
            } else {
                marginRight = (int) ((1 - info.pos_x) * Global.widthPixels);
            }

            params.setMargins(marginLeft, marginTop, marginRight, 0);
            imageRootRL.addView(tagView, params);
            tagViews.add(tagView);
        }
```

I want photo tag will show intact,but at view border will extruding.
Please help me,Thx
[image]

Comment: Look at the [9-Patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html).  And tell that guy he can swallow his own spit... with babies they spit up *on* you, not the other way around! ;)

Comment: @Jeremy Miller No no no,It's not my resource photo issue.I think it's any attribute issue about my RelativeLayout or LinearLayout.By the way,My tag view is a LinearLayout

Comment: Did you click my 9-patch link?  That has nothing to do with your photo (and my other comment was just a silly comment).  It's about how the images are stretched.  Check it out!

Comment: @Funkystein Parents do weird things with their children (and vice versa) all of the time.  This seems rather gross and I never did nor would imagine doing that to my child, but it's far from pornographic -- and if it were, I'd be flagging it for far more attention than a mod!  It is, though, quite distracting from the question!